# How to apply a generic extension to a specific generic type?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, extension-methods

Imagine i have an extension method that operates of an interface of abstract objects:

```
public static void BlowTheirWhoHoovers(this ICollection<Image> source)
{
   ...
}
```

This extension knows how to blow the who hoovers of a list of images.

**Note**:

- it's a list of **Images**, which is abstract. As long as the lists contain anything that descends from Image (e.g. `Bitmap`, `Metafile`, `PngImage`) the extension can handle it
- `source` list can by any kind of list as long as it exposes `ICollection`
- since `source` list is going to potentially have items added or removed, it is `ICollection` rather than `IEnumeration` (`IEnumeration` doesn't support modifying the list)

That's all well and good, except it doesn't work, the extension method is not found:

```
Collection<Bitmap> whoHonkers = new Collection<Bitmap>();
whoHonkers.BlowTheirWhoHoovers();
```

[image]

i assume this fails because:

- Visual Studio doesn't think `Collection` implements `ICollection<T>`
- Visual Studio doesn't think `Bitmap` descends from `Image`

Now i *can* change my extension:

```
public static void BlowTheirWhoHoovers(this Collection<Bitmap> source)
{
   ...
}
```

which *does* compile:

[image]

except it's no longer useful (it requires `Collection`, and it requires `Bitmap`), e.g. it fails to work on anything except `Collection<T>`:

```
List<Bitmap> whoHonkers = new List<Bitmap>();
whoHonkers.BlowTheirWhoHoovers();
```

It also fails on anything that it's `Bitmap`:

```
List<Metafile> whoHonkers = new List<Metafile>();
whoHonkers.BlowTheirWhoHoovers();
```

or

```
List<PngImage> whoHonkers = new List<PngImage>();
whoHonkers.BlowTheirWhoHoovers();
```

How can i apply an extension to anything that **is**:

```
ICollection<Image>
```

?

i can't force anyone to change their declaration, e.g.:

```
List<Bitmap>
```

to

```
Collection<Image>
```

**Update**:

Possible avenues of solution exploration:

- finding the syntax that allows extensions on things that the compiler should be able to do
- manually casting the list; doing the compiler's job for it

**Update#2**:

i could have simplified some of the distractions around `ICollection`, and made it `IEnumerable` (since it's a hypothetical example i can make up whatever i want). But the screenshots already show `Collection`, so i'm going to leave it as it is.

**Update#3**:

As [foson pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658578/12597), changing it to `IEnumerable` allows a way to cheat the answer. So it definitely should stay as `ICollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a covarient problem.

If you change the signature to

`public static void BlowTheirWhoHoovers(this IEnumerable<Image> source)`

you should be able to do it in .NET 4 (not SL).

The problem with varience is that if you passed into the method an `ICollection<JpegImage>`, the method itself wouldn't know that it could only add `JpegImage`s and not `Bitmap`s, defeating type saftey.  Therefore the compiler does not let you do it.  `IEnumerable`'s type parameter is covarient, as seen by the `out` keyword, while `ICollection`'s type parameter is not (since it is both in return positions and method parameter positions in the ICollection interface)

`public interface IEnumerable<out T>`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Comment: Dammit! My *real* situation specifically requires ICollection:   `public static void Merge(this ICollection<DatabaseObject> source, IEnumerable<DatabaseObject> childList)`, where the purpose of the extension *is* to add items to the collection (which IEnumerable doesn't allow). So it sounds like i'm monumentally screwed.

Comment: I always prefer functional style, where I don't modify arguments -- I'd try can you do `public static IEnumerable<DatabaseObject> Merge(IEnumerable<DatabaseObject> source, IEnumerable<DatabaseObject> childList)` instead.  (which also allows chaining)

Comment: Yeah, it just means that rather than people getting the behavior for free they now have to hunt for the "extension" class. Also i can't use the return type (`IEnumerable<DatabaseObject`), since the property is `Collection<LineItem>`.

Comment: You had the solution. If the Visual Studio type system is confused, then get rid of the types: `public static void BlowTheirWhoHoovers(this IList source)` It has to be `IList` rather than `ICollection`, because only `IList` allows the addition of items. Although i then lose what i wanted, and now `BlowTheirWhoHoovers` is available on **all** collections. Grrr.